# How to close window in outlook desktop client

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am creating a react addin. I need to close the popup window after making an api call. I used window.close() and it is working in outlook web client but it is not working in outlook desktop.

Comment: Can you provide some code and screenshots to show both case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recommend using the [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) for scenarios where you need a popup window. There is an API specifically for [closing the dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#closing-the-dialog-box) that works across all clients including Outlook Desktop